# How to save text fields values along with file uploads using single api in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a use case, in which I need to save registration form field values to the data base and also upload the user image too.

According to my knowledge, I need to use 2 different apis for storing form field values and one for uploading file. As images uploaded like, `request.files` and raw data be like, `request.body`.

Is it possible to upload both images and form field values in a single api? I need to get the `id` of user so that I can map the userId to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that.
For image you can use it multer to store image(file), and form value can be stored as well.

For multer reference you can visit [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

You have to use multer as a middleware as I have used in my router

```
router.post('/addtype', upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {

 const newExample = new Example ({
        examplename: req.body.name,
        imagePath:'/images/' + req.file.filename
    })
    newExample .save()
        .then(result => {
            res.json(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
})
```

I'm using mongoose in this example you can do same with mongodbClient

Comment: Yeah thanks. Even I'm using multer and mongoose ODM to do that. But how to save both at a time?

Comment: Am using postman to test the apis. In that am able to select either form-data or raw data types in Body. When i select form-data, I'm unable to provide raw json object to insert the data

Comment: You are storing image in database or local file?